# Break out certain time within a timeframe in excel

Tags: excel, algorithm, syntax

I am paying salaries for some workers and they have different salary depending on what time of the day they work. E.g. if they work between 06:00-22:00 they earn X and if they work between 22:00-06:00 they earn Y. The time extracted from my software take the total time worked, e.g. between 21:15-06:15, i.e. the staff will get paid differently during the time of this shift. How do I break the time out so I can chose to pay different between the different time slots. I've attached a gsheet with some example data and with two columns where the output should be:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nRrxn6tTtiNXCrssMJwRyWL2jj5TXBFVmNhKPJ_BbVg/edit#gid=0

Comment: What is the problem you have run into, and where have you gotten stuck? Not including what you tried, or not trying at all will most likely get you [downvoted](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Also people are reluctant to follow links to shared spreadsheets. It's best to include an accurate description of your data and expected in/output within your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fairly general one based on the [overlap formula](https://exceljet.net/formula/calculate-date-overlap-in-days)

For hours worked 06:00-22:00

```
=max(min(B4+(B4<A4),time(22,0,0))-max(A4,0.25),0)+max(min(B4+(B4<A4),1+TIME(22,0,0))-max(A4,1.25),0)
```

For hours worked 22:00-06:00

```
=max(min(B4,0.25)-max(A4,0),0)+max(min(B4+(B4<A4),1.25)-max(A4,time(22,0,0)),0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To detect 6-22 use below formula. `Check your sheet`.

```
=IF(AND(A4>TIME(5,30,),A4<TIME(6,30,0)),"X","")
```

To detect 22-6 use below formula

```
=IF(AND(A4>TIME(21,30,),A4<TIME(22,30,0)),"Y","")
```

Then change `X` and `Y` as your need. You can also change time frame to detect start time. I have used `1 hour` to detect shift.

Comment: Thanks for this! I would also be able to know exactly how long time each staff has worked during a shift, i.e. not only showen "x" or "y". Rather " 5.6 hours" during "X" time and "0.3 hours" during "y" time. Then I can multiply these hours for each shift since the salary depends on the hours they worked.

Comment: Then use `=IF(AND(A4>TIME(5,30,),A4<TIME(6,30,0)),TEXT(B4-A4,"h"),"")` this formula.

Comment: Thanks. For example, in cell D4 the staff should be paid for 2 minutes for it shows empty. Same case in e.g. in cell "c10" where the staff should be paud for 25 minutes during normal hours, i.e. between 06:00-22:00 and cell "D10" should only amount to 8 hours, not 8 hours 25 minutes as the staff only worked 8 hours during 22:00-06:00 and 25 minutes between 06:00-22:00

Comment: any idea @Harun24HR